# Facebook Business Manager Results metric via API (python)

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-insights

With python I’m using Insights API in order to get data (at the campaign level) of the facebook business manager report (impressions, clicks etc etc).
I’m using the following code:

```
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount

access_token = "****"
app_secret = "****"
app_id = "*****"
ad_accounts = [{"name": "***", "id": "act_****"}, {"name": "***", "id": "act_****"}]

fields = [
        'reach',
        'impressions',
        'spend',
        'clicks',
        'account_id',
        'account_name',
        'campaign_name',
        'campaign_id',
        'date_start',
        'date_stop',
        'objective',
        'inline_link_clicks',
        'inline_post_engagement',
        'inline_link_click_ctr',
        'actions',
        'estimated_ad_recallers'
    ]


params = {
    # since not less than 37 months ago
    'time_range': {'since':'2018-07-05', 'until':'2021-08-02'},
    'filtering': [],
    'level': 'campaign',
    'breakdowns': [],
    'limit': 100000,
    'use_unified_attribution_setting': True
}


for ad_account in ad_accounts:
    report_campaigns = list(AdAccount(ad_account['id']).get_insights(
        fields=fields,
        params=params,
    )
    )
```

My problem is that i need the “Results” field too. Although it is available in the fb business manager UI (see image below), “Results” is not available among all [the possible fields of the insight API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v11.0#fields).
I wonder if there is a way to have the Results metric via API.

I know I could compute this field knowing the objective of the campaign, however I have many custom objectives so this approach would be very long and I would like to avoid it if possible.
[image: fb business manager UI]

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like what you're looking for is provided under the "conversion_values" field which in turn has action_type as one of its parameters: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-action-stats/

It helps to remember that the names you see in the UI don't have to match the names coming from the API. Reading documentations may not be sexy, but given the proper attention they deserve, they almost never disappoint you.